# Secure Owin Cookie http and https

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, owin

A penetration test was done on our website and we were told that the website does not have secure cookies. This is on both Http and Https.

I have tried tones of examples and still the cookies do not have the secure ticked. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Here is what i have tried in the web config:

```
Solution 1 
<httpCookies requireSSL="true"/>

Solution 2
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />

Solution 3
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" lockItem="true"   />

Solution 4
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Layout_Simple.cshtml" cookieless="UseCookies"  requireSSL="true"   path="/Account/Login" />
    </authentication>
```

After trying each of these solution, the cookies was still not secure
[image]

I then tried code in the Global.asax.cs file. When running the website like this , the cookies was still not secure

```
 protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (Response.Cookies.Count > 0)
       {
          foreach (string s in Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
         {
           if (s == FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName || s.ToLower() == "_requestverificationtoken" || s.ToLower() == ".aspnet.applicationcookie") || s.ToLower() == "asp.net_sessionid"
           {
              Response.Cookies[s].Secure = true;                            Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Secure = true;
             Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Secure = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I also tried adding the below line in the Startup.Auth.cs file but this caused the website not to login anymore.

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
         AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
         LoginPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/Account/Login"),
         CookieSecure = Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieSecureOption.Always
```

Comment: First check if server indeed sets that flag, by inspecting response Set-Cookie header in browser dev tools

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with my ASP.Net Core 3.1 web API.  It was failing the Checkmarx scan with violations "HttpOnlyCookies" and "InsecureCookie" (despite being an API with no cookies).  I fixed it by adding this to ConfigureServices:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always;
    options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});
```